# How to combine two SUM queries in the same statement?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

I have 4 tables:

```
employees

emp-id | fname | lname

-------------

departments

dep-id | dep-name

-------------

dep-emp

emp-id | dep-id

-------------

salaries

emp-id | salary
```

I want to write a procedure that lets a user enter 2 department numbers, and get the combined salaries from all employees in those departments.

**Example**

```
Enter department no: 6
Enter second department no: 3
```

Background calculation

```
department 6 has 2 employees
employee 1 earns 25,000
employee 2 earns 22,000
Total = 47,000

department 3 has 3 employees
employee 1 earns 40,000
employee 2 earns 45,000
employee 3 earns 35,000
Total = 130,000

Combined Total = 177,000
```

Output:

```
Combined salary total for those departments is: 177,000
```

I can return SUM(salary) from employees in one department, but I can't work out how to sum two departments, and how to assign both procedure inputs correctly.

This is my procedure so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getDepartmentSalaryTotal(IN in_dep1 int(11), IN in_dep2 int(11))
SELECT SUM(salary) FROM salaries
JOIN employees
ON (salaries.emp-id = employees.emp-id)
JOIN dep-emp
ON (employees.emp-id = dep-emp.emp-id)
WHERE dep-emp.dep-id = // in_dep1 + in_dep2;
```

I'm not sure I'm approaching it correctly at all.

**UPDATE**

Java code:

```
public static int getDepartmentSalaryTotal(Connection conn, int dep1, int dep2) {
        int salaryTotal = 0;
        try {
            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("{call getDepartmentSalaryTotal(?)}");
            pst.setInt(1, dep1);
            pst.setInt(2, dep2);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                salaryTotal =  rs.getInt(1);
            }
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return salaryTotal;
    }
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Aren't you doing it in java???

Comment: @RakibulIslam Is it not possible to get the result from the sql query?

Comment: That's possible also, but if you are using java, then I think why it is needed to do harder calculation with queries. Am I right??

Comment: Hi. Would it work if you tried the WHERE statement this way? WHERE dep-emp.id = in_dep1 OR dep-emp.id = in_dep2

Comment: @RakibulIslam Well, I'm new to mysql, so I wasn't sure if this was a particularly complicated query.

Comment: @WrongASP No I don't think so. Using OR won't add the inputs.

Comment: @ovokuro You don't want to add inputs, you want to make SUM of salary (field) of every employee (record / row) where department is either in_dep1 or in_dep_2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PreparedStatement` to execute the below query:

```
select sum(salary) from salaries
where emp_id in (select emp_id from dep_emp where dep_id in (?,?));
```

Like so:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(above_sql_as_string);

// To get total salary of 10 and 20 department_id:
ps.setInt(1, 10);
ps.setInt(2, 20);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Just to know (Actually this thing is new to me), why the "?" sign is used in the query? Does that mean anything in mysql or java or those are given to simplify the answer?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the Java code. The SQL statement won't work - it doesn't recognise '?'

Comment: It's a placeholder for value. The `prepareStatement()` will send the sql to database server. After that, by setting using `setInt()` will send those params to server. It's good programming practice and removes the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @ovokuro it'll work in java. To run directly on the database, replace ? with your ids

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I've done that, the query runs but returns empty result..

Comment: @ovokuro please post what code you used in the question

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I've updated my question with the java statement. When I run the command in mysql it returns empty rows, when I run it through eclipse I get a lot of errors. I will try to get a simplified version of your answer working in mysql first, and then I will update the java code.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Also, is there a problem with the way I've used "{call method}" in my statement? Is your way better?

Comment: You don't wan't to create stored procedure for each and everything, although it can be very helpful at times.

Comment: I think an `IN` clause would be better, and to write that in a `WHERE` clause rather than part of the `JOIN ON` clause, i.e. replace last line with `where d.dep_id in (?, ?)`